# How to use custom layout for items of Select component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'd like to add some HTML elements to options of *Select* component. Here is the example:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="items">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of ($items | async)" [value]="item.id">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <br>
    <small>{{item.description}}</small>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Although it works and looks trivial there is a little issue with this approach. When option is choosen value of *Select* component is `{{item.name}}{{item.description}}` like "Kitchen knifePerfect handcrafted knife for your kitchen." but I need to use only item name as *Select* component value.

Does anyone know the way how to cope with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only suggest a workaround for this. 
I've created an input element and disabled it, so material will not capture this element as text to show.

Demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-429gpt-39njqu?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

Comment: Definitely it is a duct tape but it works! :) Thanks for your answer!